# Facebook Likebox "allowTransparency" gives invalid XHTML in W3C validator

Tags: html, facebook, validation, xhtml, iframe

**What I did:** I embedded Facebook Like Box on my otherwise "XHTML 1.0 Transitional" webpage. The source code of Facebook Like Box is as given by Facebook:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fplatform&amp;width=292&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;stream=false&amp;header=true&amp;height=62"
  scrolling="no"
  frameborder="0"
  style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:62px;"
  allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
```

**What W3C validator says:** When I check the webpage in W3C validator, it gives following error:

> Line 600, Column 421: there is no attribute "allowTransparency"

But, IE needs `allowTransparency="true">` to work.

**Expected Solution:** What should I do to make it validate as XHTML 1.0 Transitional while keeping Facebook like box on my webpage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can write two codes for it. One with `allowTransparency` with if statement for IE and another without it. This way, it can be done. So, use this embed code with conditional HTML comments:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fplatform&amp;width=292&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;stream=false&amp;header=true&amp;height=62"
  scrolling="no"
  frameborder="0"
  style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:62px;"
  allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>

<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fplatform&amp;width=292&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;stream=false&amp;header=true&amp;height=62"
  scrolling="no"
  frameborder="0"
  style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:62px;">
</iframe>

<!--<![endif]-->
```

This will validate the XHTML since the iframe code is commented out and you can use allowTransparency too.

**EDIT**: Closed the iframe as pointed out by staticbeast in a comment.

Comment: Even though this is a correct answer, I really hate this. The idea of adding a maintenance overhead like this, just to work around the validator seems to run completely counter to the whole point of validation.

Comment: @Alohci, yes I hate this too. Maybe Facebook should give a code which is valid in the first place.

Comment: Just a warning: at the end of your second `<iframe>` declaration, you are missing a closing `>` after the `style=""` block :)

Answer (score 3):

If IE **truly needs** `allowTransparency="true"` to work, then you're not going to be able to create 100% valid XHTML 1.0 Transitional markup.

...but why does IE need that attribute? What happens when it's omitted?

---

If you're really that concerned about W3C validation (I don't think it's worth it, but that's just me), then you could apply the same `iframe` attribute using JavaScript. **I'm not recommending this,*** but you *could* do it:

```
document.getElementById('theIFrameID').allowTransparency = true;
```

---

*****because I don't think that the goal of creating 100% validated markup justifies using JavaScript to accomplish something that's otherwise-identical to the static markup.

Comment: IE needs it to allow transparency. Please read it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fplatform&amp;width=292&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_es=true&amp;stream=false&amp;header=true&amp;height=62"
  scrolling="no"
  frameborder="0"
  style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:62px; allowTransparency:true;">
</iframe>
```

I don't know why they used styles to do everything except allow transparency.So just throw it in with the rest of the styles and it should validate.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tested it recently, but I think you're allowed to have comments within HTML tags, so just wrap the `allowTransparency` in an IE conditional comment:

```
<!--[if ie]> allowTransparency="true" <![end if]-->
```

To have IE see it, and everything else ignore it. This should also be valid XHTML, since comments are ignored by browsers, and conditional comments parses only by IE.

Comment: OK. I will try it. Can you somehow assure that comments INSIDE tags work fine in IE6+.

Comment: @WhatIsOpenId: I can't see any reason why they wouldn't, but the only IE I have available is 8. It seems to work there, and conditional comments certainly work from 6 and upwards, I think in 5 too, but I've not even **seen** IE 5 in over 6 years.

Answer (score 1):

For me is the best way use a jQuery like this:

For facebook like button. I set class="likebtn" and then in .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".likebtn").attr('allowTransparency', 'true');
});
```

Thats all ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Leave it as is. "allowTransparency" only means something to IE, and it will be ignored otherwise. Validation is a tool for checking your document against the standard, not an end in itself. You are knowingly writing something outside of the HTML standard for a particular case; acknowledge that rather than trying to hide it.

Comment: But the client wants their website to be 100% valid in W3C validator :(